# jquery fixed table header on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a data table this table read his data from `mysql` database

I use this jquery and css to fixed the header of the table on scroll

```
;(function($) {
   $.fn.fixMe = function() {
      return this.each(function() {
         var $this = $(this),
            $t_fixed;
         function init() {
            $this.wrap('<div class="table-responsive" />');
            $t_fixed = $this.clone();
            $t_fixed.find("tbody").remove().end().addClass("fixed").insertBefore($this);
            resizeFixed();
         }
         function resizeFixed() {
            $t_fixed.find("th").each(function(index) {
               $(this).css("width",$this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth()+"px");
            });
         }
         function scrollFixed() {
            var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
            tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
            tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find("thead").height();
            if(offset < tableOffsetTop || offset > tableOffsetBottom)
               $t_fixed.hide();
            else if(offset >= tableOffsetTop && offset <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden"))
               $t_fixed.show();
         }
         $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
         $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
         init();
      });
   };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("table").fixMe();
   $(".up").click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
   }, 2000);
 });
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="table-responsive" >
    <table class='ol-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf table-bordered'>
        <thead class='cf'>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan='2'>#</th>
                <th rowspan='2'>Staff
                </th>
                <th rowspan='2'>MyTask</th>
                <th rowspan='2'>Status</th>
                <th rowspan='2'>Description</th>
                <th rowspan='2'>transfered</th>
                <th colspan='3'>Planning</th>
                <th rowspan='2'>Date
                </th>
                <th rowspan='2'>Project</th>
                <th rowspan='2'>Type</th>
                <th rowspan='2'>Frequency</th>
                <th rowspan='2'>Priority</th>
                <th rowspan='2'>Note</th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th> Start Date</th>
                <th> Due Date</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

The problem is when i scroll down the column width change and the title in the header don't match the content of the table body

you can check in the link below

this the code on https://fiddle.jshell.net/mhmd2991/oy764es6/12/

How Can i fixed ??!!

Comment: There's a jQuery plugin for this, try that one out: http://www.fixedheadertable.com/

Answer (score 0):

Separating the content into 2 tables won't work correctly with the desired layout you want to have, because **width of each cell is affected by the cell's content, and the whole table width gets its layout by each cell's width and height**.

Look for different approach.

Comment: you mean put the thead in a table and the tbody in another table ?

Comment: @mohamadmohamad Yes